# Acceptable to edit an answerer's comment into his answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, answer-quality

A few days ago I asked [When did Morpheus find out the Oracle is a program?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81888/31936)

I received a good answer from [Nerrolken](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20221/nerrolken) but we had a short discussion in the comments about an issue I mentioned in my question (specifically, why didn't anyone try to unplug the Oracle if they thought she was human?). Nerrolken came up with some good reasons and I asked him to edit that into his answer, but I've received no response (and he's been active since then).

**Would it be acceptable for me to copy the text of his comment into his answer?**

Specifically, I would be appending the text of the second to last comment below his answer minus the initial "Fair enough. :)":

> Fair enough. :) As for questioning why someone else didn't unplug her before his time, if he ever wondered about it, there are plenty of reasonable explanations: being in the Matrix allows her greater access to the blue pill candidates, for example, and easier access by any given ship that might need her. Hell, since a precog needn't fear the Agents, maybe she simply prefers it there. (She's quirky enough to just "prefer my old house" or something.) But mostly, I think he just wouldn't presume to question her like that: she's the Oracle, if she's still in the Matrix she no doubt has a reason.

Normally, I would consider such an edit to be too substantial and I wouldn't do it (or accept it if suggested). However, I think it *might* be acceptable for the following reasons:

1. I would be copying his exact words, so it's not like I would be putting words into his mouth.
2. My (original, unedited) question specifically asks about this issue so the answer is not entirely complete without addressing it.
3. [Comments are intended to be temporary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and I wouldn't want this information to be lost.

Comment: Good question. I wouldn't do it, personally - but I'm not one for adding information to anyone else's answers.

Comment: In this particular case, why not ask the answerer to add those details to their answer?

Comment: @Keen I did. The last comment is mine, asking him to add it.

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail. Never comment before coffee!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, I wouldn't think twice. I've done similar edits. However, since you've already asked the answerer to do it, I would wait a while to give them the opportunity to do so.

Comment: I agree. Comments can become a bit 'noisy', even if they are relevant and on-topic. I for one used to think that the point must not have been important if it wasn't in the answer. Assumedly, some new users may also be in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an excellent idea. Then again, I also seem to be a mildly controversial figure in terms of editing people's answers, so take that with a grain of salt.